# Unable to merge dex error when building my android project

Tags: android, gradle, dex

I am trying to build my android project and getting the error "Unable to merge dex"

I tried different options that are mentioned in other posts. Some of them are

- Remove unused libraries
- Add multidexenabled=true to gradle file
- Add implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3' to gradle file
- Clean , delete .gradle folder and rebuild

The problem is still present and am not sure what is wrong. Kindly please share your thoughts.

```
Error:Execution failed for task         
':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: 
com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex
```

My app/build.gradle file

```
            apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

            android {
                compileSdkVersion 27

                defaultConfig {
                    applicationId "app.resta.com.restaurantapp"
                    minSdkVersion 23
                    targetSdkVersion 27
                    versionCode 1
                    versionName "1.0"
                    multiDexEnabled true
                }
                buildTypes {
                    release {
                        minifyEnabled false
                        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
                    }
                }
                compileOptions {
                    targetCompatibility 1.7
                    sourceCompatibility 1.7
                }
            }
            repositories {
                maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
            }
            dependencies {
                compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
                testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
                implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
                implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
                implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.2'

                compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.2'
                implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
                implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.1.5'
                implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.5'
                implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:4.1.0'
                annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'
                implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
            }

            apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with support libraries `27.1.1` it builds:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.1.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.5'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:4.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

if not, add the whole `DexArchiveMergerException` and not only that notice, which tells nothing.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was struggling with this for almost a day. Didn't think it will be solved by incrementing the version. Can I please know how were you able to debug this? Is it trail and error or is there some way that you debugged the issue?

Comment: @marin I just copied and pasted it into a `build.gradle` and did what it told me to do.